# Erlang: Remove single element from proplist

Tags: list, erlang

I'm trying to remove a single top element from a proplist. How would I go about doing this.

I have a proplist like so:

```
[{listA,[a,b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}]
```

So how would I remove the top element from listA?

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html <- This might help.

Comment: As I'm using a proplist, I've attempted to use proplist:delete, however this surely would delete all the elements in listA, whereas I just want to delete one.

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#lookup-2

Could you use something like this to "index" the first element and then delete it?

Comment: How would I use an exported function from lists on a list inside a property list. For example on listB in: T = [{listA, {a,b,c]}, {listB, [d,e]}]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`lists:keytake/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keytake-3) to get the element, then modify it and put it back:

```
1> List = [{listA,[a,b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}].
[{listA,[a,b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}]
2> lists:keytake(listA, 1, List).
{value,{listA,[a,b,c]},[{listB,[d,e]}]}
3> {value, {listA, [_|Items]}, Options} = lists:keytake(listA, 1, List).
{value,{listA,[a,b,c]},[{listB,[d,e]}]}
4> [{listA, Items}|Options].
[{listA,[b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}]
```

Comment: This removes the whole list, would it be the same principle to remove one element, just with a different function?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @User Yes, just bind the result to a new variable: `NewList = [{listA, Items}|Options].`

Comment: Instead of binding it to a new variable can I replace over the existing variable?

Comment: No you can't. Variables are notre mutable in erlang.

Answer (score 2):

```
remove_head(Name, PropList) ->
    lists:reverse(
      remove_head(Name, PropList, [])
    ).

remove_head(_Name, [], Results) -> Results;

remove_head(Name, [ {Name, [_H|T]} | Tail ], Results) ->
    remove_head(Name, Tail, [{Name, T}|Results]);

remove_head(Name, [H|T], Results) -> 
    remove_head(Name, T, [H|Results]).
```

Example:

```
47> c(my).
{ok,my}

48> P1= [
48> {listA, [a,b,c]},
48> {listB, [d,e]}   
48> ].
[{listA,[a,b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}]

49> my:remove_head(listA, P1).                                                     
[{listA,[b,c]},{listB,[d,e]}]

50> P2 = [
50> {listA, [a,b,c]},
50> {listB, [d,e]}, 
50> {listA, [y, x, x]}
50> ].
[{listA,[a,b,c]},{listB,[d,e]},{listA,[y,x,x]}]

51> my:remove_head(listA, P2).
[{listA,[b,c]},{listB,[d,e]},{listA,[x,x]}]
```